# cut last string to one letter after dot character with preg_replace

Tags: php

I have a php script example, but in this instance my script I want to cut the last word to one letter only, example of the word "one two three" turns into 'one.two.t'
How do I solve it? please help.

The example of my php script

```
<?php

$str = 'arya dwi pangga';
$str = preg_replace( '/ /', '.', $str );
echo $str;

?>
```

The above example will output: arya.dwi.pangga  but i want the output arya.dwi.p , how do I solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'arya dwi pangga';
$str = str_replace(' ', '.', $str);
$cut = strrpos($str, '.')+2;
$str = substr($str, 0, $cut);

echo $str;
```

output: arya.dwi.p

You don't need `preg_match()` for easy replaces like finding a space and replacing for a dot, just use `str_replace()` if you don't have complex patterns to find.

I jused `strrpos()` to find the last ocurrence of the needle ('.' in this case), added +2 (the dot itself and the next letter) and know at wich position cut the string, then used `substr()` to cut it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'arya dwi pangga'; 
$str1 = preg_replace( '/ /', '.', $str ); 
$str2 = substr(strrchr($str1, '.'), 1,1);
$string = explode('.', $str1);
array_pop($string);
$string1 = implode('.', $string);
echo "<br>";
echo $string1.".".$str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'arya dwi pangga'; 
$str = preg_split('/\s+/', $str); //Split string by space characters

$last = count($str) - 1 ;
$str[$last] = substr($str[$last], 0, 1);  //Leave only the first character of last element
$str = implode(".", $str);        //Get the full string back with dots instead of spaces.

echo $str ;
```